# Create a librairie for Springboot using gradle without doing bootJar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-test

I developed a controllerAdvice that I want to put it in a librairie that will be used by several microservices;
Since my library is using spring annotations I m adding plugins and dependencies for springboot. However when I add

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
```

this adds me a bootJar step in the build step. The bootJar asking that I should have a main class for the spring boot the thing that I dont want too, since my jar is only a library and not a springboot application.

here is a part of my gradle.build script :

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


group = 'com.test'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url = artifactoryRepoUrl
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas")

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6')
    annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6')
}
```

how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you'd benefit from using Spring Boot's dependency management in isolation. This will take care of managing your dependencies versions, while leaving your project building a normal jar rather than a Spring Boot fat jar. The Gradle plugin's reference documentation [describes how to do this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#managing-dependencies-using-in-isolation). This first step is to depend on the plugin without applying it. If you're using the `plugins` block, that would look like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE' apply false
}
```

In your case it looks as it removing `apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'` would be sufficient.

You're already applying the dependency management plugin so the remaining step is to configure Boot's dependency management:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES
    }
}
```

This will allow you to continue to declare dependencies with no version. You can then run the `jar` task to build a normal jar that's suitable for use as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks, that leads me to find my issue, in fact I think if I ommit the plugin: 'org.springframework.boot' the compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') was not able to find a version to use ...

Comment: so the issue is correcte by adding ther versions as     compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.4.RELEASE'

Comment: mavenBom SpringBootPlugin.BOM_COORDINATES is sufficient

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to disable the `bootJar` task and enable the `jar` task (which creates an ordinary jar rather than an executable jar). Add the following snippet in your *build.gradle* file:

```
bootJar {
    enabled = false
}
jar {
    enabled = true
}
```

Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/